# How do I get the Caffeine app working on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

The [Caffeine app](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) for preventing sleep/screen lock is not working on macOS Mojave.

Did I miss a setting to FAQ on making it work with macOS 10.14?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  The way your question is currently written, it could be closed as off-topic.  You can help prevent this from happening by editing your question to include the problem you're having and what you've already done to resolve it.  For example, what alternatives to Caffeine did you try and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: Have you tried Caffine app for the Mac? http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/

Comment: @jmh not working on mojave

Comment: What do you mean by „not working“? Does is it not start, does it not prevent sleep? Did you check the man page tinder whether parameters changed?

Comment: Caffinated is a maintained app that was last updated in Sept, 2018 so it may support Mojave.  Is $1 at the app store. But i have no idea if it will work.

Comment: @nohillside mbp catching sleep even with caffeine on - maybe something local, but its not working anymore as intended.

Comment: Can you add some specific usage?

Comment: Did you consider using Caffeine but upgrading the security as @Eisenknurr recommends? 
Thanks!

Comment: @eMarine I went with a clone

Comment: Maybe is a good idea to change the first question to make cleat that actually Caffeine works with the current version. The information about available similar solutions is good, but in the first question you say that caffeine doesn't work, and that's untrue.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

TLDR: Access to the permissions in Mac OSX Mojave have changed. You have two options:

1. [Download updated version of Caffeine that I fixed.](https://intelliscapesolutions.com/apps/caffeine) See story below.
2. [Update preferences to allow Caffeine access it needs.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339355/116392) (via other answer to this question)

---

While this question wasn't entirely clear on whether the issue was with the `caffeinate` command built in to macOS or the Caffeine utility written by Tomas Franzén of Lighthead Software, the comments and other answers seem to imply the latter.

After encountering the issue myself, I reached out to Tomas and inquired about taking over the development of Caffeine. He graciously has provided the source code under an MIT license, and I've made a quick updated version available [here](https://intelliscapesolutions.com/apps/caffeine) that will prompt for the needed accessibility permissions when running on Mojave.

I will be bringing additional support for Mojave as well as some improvements in the near future, but wanted to put this here for others who come across this question like I did and would like to continue using Caffeine.

Comment: @charlie137 I see that following Beau Smith's edit to this answer, you have since removed it as the accepted answer. Was there a problem with the edit? Given that there is now a released version of Caffeine supporting macOS Mojave, this would indeed answer the question at hand.

Comment: would you please fix the persistent blue highlight when right clicking on the menu bar icon ?

Comment: I am using the new version AND have added it to my Accessibility settings - and still it isn't working. As far as this being open sourced - I tried to look for a github repo to no avail - can you point me to that and maybe I can look into the problem/fix myself?

Comment: If Caffeine is now open source under an MIT licence will a repo be provided somewhere. It would be nice to see this on github

Comment: for others looking it is here: https://github.com/tomasf/caffeine

Comment: Thanks @Justin, I had missed the earlier comment from Justin Phiony asking about that. That repo is indeed the one that Tomas uploaded when I inquired about Caffeine, and what I based the current version on. I didn't get a chance to post the updated repo with my fixes and new features, but I'll do that soon and add a comment here with the link.

Answer (score 58):

Caffeine is still working! However, Apple has upped its security and privacy model a bit and caffeine fell prey to that. What you have to do to get it working properly again is the following:

- Open System Preferences
- Click Security & Privacy
- Click the Privacy tab
- In the left column, select Accessibility
- If needed, click the lock icon in the lower left and enter your password to unlock your settings
- Click the `+` button and select your Caffeine app to allow it to control your Mac
- Restart Caffeine

[image: System Preferences screenshot]

Comment: +1 Great fix, this worked for me! Why change to an alternative when the original one still works!

Answer (score 19):

Here are 2 alternative you can try that do the same as caffeine.

[Amphetamine, a full-on Caffeine replacement](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12)

and

[KeepingYouAwake, an up-to-date Caffeine clone](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/releases)

Comment: I have tried both of these, and they work well. I prefer the Amphetamine, for reasons I can't remember now, but I'd definitely recommend checking them both out.

Comment: +1 for KeepingYouAwake. Using since Sierra and just upgraded to Mojave. Works like a charm.

Comment: +1 as well for KeepingYouAwake. Quality software.

Comment: Also: https://github.com/domzilla/Caffeine for Sonoma

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK, `caffeinate` remains in Mojave, and it is certainly in High Sierra and Mojave. `caffeinate` is a command line utility; i.e. you invoke it from the terminal. If this is what you mean by "manual entry" then I'll guess you're not keen on doing things from the command line.

However, `caffeinate` is [quite easy to use.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamus.github.io/blob/master/MacStuff.md#2-how-do-i-prevent-my-mac-from-sleeping-) It also has the advantage of being supported by Apple, doesn't require cluttering your system with additional apps that will require your time to maintain/upgrade. I could go on, but...

So that's my answer. I mostly just wanted to make it clear that the `caffeinate` utility has not been deprecated by Apple.

#### EDIT:

Note that `caffeinate` will NOT prevent an [automatic logout](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/23/automatically-log-out-of-a-mac-after-a-period-of-inactivity/). Check to make sure you have not selected that option; `caffeinate` is powerless against a logout.

Comment: Just be sure to spell it correctly. i looked for it earlier and spelled it caffinate which looks ok but is wrong. Seamus spelled it correctly as caffeinate..

Comment: No, manual entry would be script/copy-paste one-liner. I was looking for the same app like Caffeine, that wasn't updated since 2009. And it finally just lost its magic on mojave.

Comment: I believe, and could of course be mistaken, that Caffeine is just a GUI wrapper for `caffeinate`.

Comment: I tried `caffeinate` but it doesn't work for my use-case. I have a malfunctioning Hall effect sensor that spuriously signals clamshell closed at random but even with `caffeinate`, it still goes to the lock screen. Trying `KeepMeAwake`.

Comment: @Barry: Not sure, but lock screen and sleep may be different things??

Comment: @Seamus It's more complicated than your random guess. Lock screen isn't the issue, there needs to be a way to block the clamshell closing signal which causes the display lock. Display lock should continue working. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Barry: No, I'm sorry, only random guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there—I’m the creator of an alternative called **Theine**. Back in 2015 I’ve decided to create my own caffeine-like app because of the lack of support for retina displays.

▶ Download: https://itunes.apple.com/app/theine-2/id955848755

It’s available on the Mac App Store and *doesn’t* require Accessibility (== admin) privileges at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below will start `caffeinate -s` supported by Apple as a macos launchctl daemon on computer startup.

```
; cat >~/ze.caffeinate.plist <<'EOF'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>ze.caffeinate</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/caffeinate</string>
        <string>-s</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF

; sudo mv ~/ze.caffeinate.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/

; sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/ze.caffeinate.plist
...

; sudo launchctl list |grep caffeinate                          
4921    0   ze.caffeinate
```